# How to add a vector of variable names to a data frame in R?

Tags: r

I have a vector of variable names that contain values I want to add in the data frame.

For example `var_add=c("var1","var2")`

Here the `var1` and `var2` are the name of the variables that I want to add in the data frame.

Here is the code i have written

```
for (i in var_add){
   assign(paste("data_frame$",var_add[i],sep=''),get(var_add[i]))
}
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is easy with `mget`. Here's an example.

```
dat <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 2:4)
#   a b
# 1 1 2
# 2 2 3
# 3 3 4

var1 <- 3:5
var2 <- 4:6

varnames <- c("var1", "var2")

dat[varnames] <- mget(varnames)

dat
#   a b var1 var2
# 1 1 2    3    4
# 2 2 3    4    5
# 3 3 4    5    6
```

Comment: I am getting and error`Error in .Internal(mget(x, envir, mode, ifnotfound, inherits)) : 
  'envir' is missing`

Comment: @user3401208 What did you try?

Comment: I have copied the exact solution you have written but i am getting the error message Error in .Internal(mget(x, envir, mode, ifnotfound, inherits)) : 
  'envir' is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Using `assign`  (@Sven Hohenstein's dataset)

```
var_add <- c("var1", "var2")

for(i in var_add){
assign('dat', `[[<-`(get('dat'), i, value=get(i)))
}
dat
#  a b var1 var2
#1 1 2    3    4
#2 2 3    4    5
#3 3 4    5    6
```

Comment: This works but can you explain your solution so that i can use it in other problem. More specifically what is `[[<-`(get('dat')

Comment: @user3401208.  It is assigning the `var_add`variables to the dataset `dat`.  May be something like;   `dat[var_add[1]] <- get(var_add[1]); dat[var_add[2]] <- get(var_add[2])`.  You could try reading `?Extract`, <http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Subset-assignment>